# jQuery script won't work on CSS tab menu

Tags: jquery

I was just about to try out a CSS tab menu working with jQuery.
Since I'm a beginner in JavaScript/jQuery, but having experience in PHP and stuff, I took the code off of [this tutorial page](http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-tabs-with-html-css-and-jquery).

Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work properly - since all CSS and HTML works fine, the jQuery script doesn't register any click actions, so when you choose a different tab there's no changing action for which the script is in charge.
I put the jQuery code from the tutorial page into my php file, where the html stuff is also located, in this script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
```

I tried out some things considering this script thing and changing the position of the script, but it still wouldn't work.

I'm not quite sure if I've done any mistakes by binding in the script, but strangely this whole thing isn't working on JS Fiddle either.
https://jsfiddle.net/w88mjf3p/

So, does anyone with a trained eye concerning jQuery and JS see any mistakes there? I'd appreciate your help very much! Thank you!

Comment: You haven't added jQuery to your fiddle. You'll also likely need JQuery UI if you are using their tabs code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as Lee Taylos is saying - you forgot to include jQuery in jsfiddle and that's the reasone. Please enable it here and click Run.

[image]

Comment: Apparently the problem concerning JS Fiddle is fixed now, thanks!
**But on my webspace it still doesn't work**, I've posted the code of my PHP file here: [http://hastebin.com/owijuyokog.xml](http://hastebin.com/owijuyokog.xml)

Comment: Try dividing those two scripts into separate sections. I think the way you are using jquery code together with jquery library include is not correct. Please see here: http://hastebin.com/bokiwihowu.xml

Comment: That's the solution, thank you very much! I actually tried this, but I didn't write the type="javascript/text" in the first <script>-line, only where the 'real script' began.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! :) Can you mark this as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to look at your php file to see how you included the jQuery library. it should be fine in the header or footer in this case, just make sure you embed it before your javascript function. Also, don't forget the `</script>` tag

As for JSFiddle the simple mistake you made was that in the javasript window you have to specify you are using jquery as a library.  That will make it work there.

[JSFiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYgsF.png)

Comment: @Lee I placed the script right in the head section, meanwhile the JS Fiddle problem is fixed, but it still doesn't work on my webserver.
I've posted the whole code [on here](http://hastebin.com/owijuyokog.xml).
Is there something wrong with binding in the qQuery lib via GoogleApi?

Comment: Definitely something wrong with the Google Api version.  Use the Jquery CDN one instead: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>`